# How to handle user privilege in spring security and inside thyemeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm not new to java (i did some projects with javafx and jee ) but I'm new to the whole spring thing
Here is what my scenario is
All users have same level of access but some have more accee defiened by their role in the database ( there can be upto 25!(yes that is factorial) roles all created dynamically by the main admin) . 
My template is made of 3 fragments (header with admin links that are available to users associated to their roles , side bar available to everyone and footer) 
So I'm stuck in how to make a global variable for the header part to check the logged in user on each page load and choose the correct links 
I know how to do this with jee and jsp but not with spring

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a repository and hold your session data after login like below

```
@Repository
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class LoginRepository {

    private String accessToken;  
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String userId;
    private String rolename;
    private String department;
}
```

then use `@ControllerAdvice` to pass this in every `Model`

```
 @Autowired
    LoginRepository settings;
    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(Model model) {

            model.addAttribute("rolenamecode", settings.getRolename());
        .......

}
```

Then based on your role or other parameters (`th:if`) you can load your links in you page

Comment: as i mentioned earlier i'm new to spring, can you give me some hints on how to do this after login with spring security?

Comment: You can follow this https://blog.rimon.xyz/2017/05/implementing-oauth2-in-spring-boot-with.html?fbclid=IwAR2mlcp3o--eumIDe1382nQo_VqvSKu04a1aMxpqZ-2Rzb0noSgtxmp2HuU for spring security implementation